# Dimension of the set of $2\times 2$ matrices which commute with a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am reading some linear algebra notes I have found online, and there is an exercise which asks to prove that

> if $A\in \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $U:=\{B\in \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R}):AB=BA\}$ then $\dim(U)\geq 2$.

Now, it is easy to see that $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and, by fixing some matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and multiplying it by the elements of the standard basis of $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ we get that a matrix $B\in U$ is a multiple of the identity matrix, ie $B=bI_{2},\ b\in\mathbb{R}$ and since $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ don't necessarily belong to $U$ ($A$ should be a diagonal matrix for this condition to hold as it can be easily seen) it looks like $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ is the only basis vector of this space so **it seems to me that the only thing we can say in general is that $\dim(U)\geq 1$ so there is a typo in the notes and it should ask to prove that $\dim(U)\geq 1$, not $\dim(U)\geq 2$**: is this correct? Thanks

Comment: One other matrix that is always in U is A, so if $A$ is not a multiple of the identity than dim(U)>=2. If $A$ is a multiple of the identity U=M_2(R^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space $U$ contains the identity matrix and it also contains $A$ itself. So, unless $A=\lambda\operatorname{Id}$ for some scalar $\lambda$, $\dim U\geqslant\dim\operatorname{span}\{\operatorname{Id},A\}=2$. And if indeed $A=\lambda\operatorname{Id}$ for some scalar $\lambda$, then $U=\Bbb M_2(\Bbb R)$, in which case $\dim U=4$.

Comment: ah, I had the solution in front of me, I don't know how I couldn't see that. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help.